Is there a way to resolve ip address in quickfixj in every connection attempt?
Can Quickfixj resolve ip address from hostname everytime while it is trying to initiate the connection after the connection got failed?
Currently we have an alias of host which might change when the acceptor process gets restarted. Quickfixj initiator is trying to connect to the old ip address and failing. Is there a way to resole ip address in every connection attempt?

Do you mean from the remote exchange or for local? For remote you can do session.getResponder().getRemoteAddress() and for local you can try 127.0.0.1 or localhost

https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/pull/384 is probably what you want to do. However, it is only part of the next major release and we have no date for that yet. Possibly you could merge that PR into a personal branch and build your own version?
